# Using python to analyse bigrams in a string of text

Tags: python, cryptography, n-gram, frequency-analysis, vigenere

I am trying to use python to help me crack Vigenère ciphers. I am fairly new to programming but I've managed to make an algorithm to analyse bigram frequencies in a string of text. This is what I have so far:

```
import nltk, string
from nltk import bigrams

Ciphertext = str(input("What is the text to be analysed?"))

#Removes spacing and punctuation to make the text easier to analyse
def Remove_Formatting(str):
    str = str.upper()
    str = str.strip()
    str = str.replace(' ','')
    str = str.translate(str.maketrans({a:None for a in string.punctuation}))
    return str

Ciphertext = Remove_Formatting(Ciphertext)

#Score is meant to increase if most common bigrams are in the text
def Bigram(str):
    Common_Bigrams = ['TH',        'EN',        'NG',
                      'HE',        'AT',        'AL',
                      'IN',        'ED',        'IT',
                      'ER',        'ND',        'AS',
                      'AN',        'TO',        'IS',
                      'RE',        'OR',        'HA',
                      'ES',        'EA',        'ET',
                      'ON',        'TI',        'SE',
                      'ST',        'AR',        'OU',
                      'NT',        'TE',        'OF']
    Bigram_score = int(0)
    for bigram in str:
        if bigram in Common_Bigrams:
            Bigram_score += 1
            return Bigram_score

Bigram(Ciphertext)

print (Bigram_score)
```

However when I try to run with a text this I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Tony/Desktop/Bigrams.py", line 36, in <module>
    print (Bigram_score)
NameError: name 'Bigram_score' is not defined
```

What does this mean? I thought I have already defined Bigram_score as a variable, and I've tried everything but it still returns as an error this way or that. What have I done wrong? Please help...

Thanks in advance,

Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make Bigram_score global, like this:

```
def Bigram(string): # don't override str
    global Bigram_score
    Common_Bigrams = ['TH',        'EN',        'NG',
                      'HE',        'AT',        'AL',
                      'IN',        'ED',        'IT',
                      'ER',        'ND',        'AS',
                      'AN',        'TO',        'IS',
                      'RE',        'OR',        'HA',
                      'ES',        'EA',        'ET',
                      'ON',        'TI',        'SE',
                      'ST',        'AR',        'OU',
                      'NT',        'TE',        'OF']
    Bigram_score = 0 # that 0 is an integer is implicitly understood
    for bigram in string:
        if bigram in Common_Bigrams:
            Bigram_score += 1
            return Bigram_score
```

You could also bind the returned result from the `Bigram` function to a variable, like this:

```
Bigram_score = Bigram(Ciphertext)

print(Bigram_score)
```

or:

```
print(Bigram(Ciphertext))
```

When you assign values to variables in a function, they are local and bound to that function. If a function returns anything, the returned value must be bound to a variable to be reused properly (or used directly).

This is an example of how it works:

```
spam = "spam" # global spam variable

def change_spam():
    spam = "ham" # setting the local spam variable
    return spam

change_spam()
print(spam) # prints spam

spam = change_spam() # here we assign the returned value to global spam
print(spam) # prints ham
```

In addition, your for loop loops over unigrams instead of bigrams. Let us take a closer look:

```
for x in "hellothere":
    print(x)
```

This will print unigrams. We therefore rename the `bigram` variable in your code to see where there are some logical problems.

```
for unigram in string:
    if unigram in Common_Bigrams:
        print("bigram hit!")
```

Since there are no unigrams that are identical with any bigrams, `"bigram hit!"` will never be printed. We could try to get bigrams with a different approach, using a while loop and an index number.

```
index = 0
n = 2 # for bigrams
while index < len(string)-(n-1): # minus the length of n-1 (n-grams)
    ngram = string[index:index+n] # collect ngram
    index += 1 # important to add this, otherwise the loop is eternal!
    print(ngram)
```

Next, just include in the loop what you want to do with the bigram.

Comment: I have tried the 'global' function, and that worked, thank you!

Comment: However, Bigram_score turned out to be '0', which is not what I would expect. Is there something wrong with the algorithm?

Comment: Yes, I can see a problem with your algorithm. It is in the for loop, where you seem to be looping over each individual character. In fact, you look at unigrams and ask if they equal any of the bigrams. They will never do so, and leaves you with a score of 0. Or at least I would guess that that's the thing.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense because it says: for bigram in string

Comment: It's the same logic as with the spam. You name the variable. Just that you name the variable `bigram` doesn't mean there are bigrams in there. You could simply change the variable name to `unigram` for now to see what I'm at. I'll update my answer to cover this.

Comment: Updated the answer to cover the unigram problem. Hope it helps!